# Class1 has ArrayList<Class2>, but Class2 has a single Class1 instance?

Tags: java, class, reference, instance

In my project i have a Store class, i also have a Manager class. Now a manager can manager many stores, but a store can have one manager. This results in:

MANAGER CLASS HAS:
ArrayList stores;

STORE CLASS HAS:
Manager manager;

I need to be able to reference a manager from the store, but i also need to get all the stores from a manager.

So i need to be able to do:
manager.getStores();
&
store.getManager();

This creates a cycle of creating new object instances and a need to keep reading from a database. I am unsure how to go about this from both a design and practical viewpoint, I am still quite new to this, so if someone could help me that would be amazing!

Comment: I think it would help if you share the actual code of your class definitions with said properties, and those `get` methods.

Comment: @NickRolando https://gyazo.com/2991cdce7d6ed6ea4d66fd777dc4bf25
https://gyazo.com/dc115217078e143bcb1cbfba7a1ed1c9

This is where the issue lies, as they never directly reference the same object. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one reason to store references in both directions: for performance. Unless you need to store and search a lot of data then keep it as simple as possible.

```
class Store {
    private Manager manager;

    public Manager hasManager(Manager manager) {
        return this.manager.equals(manager);
    }
}

class StoreList {
    private final List<Store> stores;

    public Stream<Store> getManagedStores(Manager manager) {
        return stores.stream().filter(s -> s.hasManager(manager));
    }
}
```

This automatically enforces referential integrity because a store can only have one manager. It encapsulates logic about store management in the list of stores rather than the manager. The nice thing about this is that the Manager class doesn't need to know anything at all about stores: the same class could be used for managing restaurants without any changes.

If you really need a `getStores` in the `Manager` class then you will need to implement some validations:

```
class StoreList {
    public boolean hasStore(Store store) {
        return stores.contains(store);
    }
}

class Manager {
    private final StoreList stores;

    public boolean hasStoreInStoreList(Store store) {
        return stores.hasStore(store);
    }

    public Stream<Store> getStores() {
        return stores.getManagedStores(this);
    }
}

class Store {
    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        if (manager.hasStoreInStoreList(this))
            this.manager = manager;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Manager for different stores");
    }
}
```

If performance is a concern then a common approach is to use a cache. This is a well understood design pattern that involves keeping a copy of the results of a search to avoid having to repeat the search. The cache is purged if the reference changes forcing the search to be run again. It might look something like this:

```
class Manager {
    private Optional<List<Store>> managedStores = Optional.empty();

    public void purgeCache() {
        managedStores = Optional.empty();
    }

    public Stream<Store> getStores() {
        if (!managedStores.isPresent())
            managedStores = Optional.of(stores.getManagedStores(this)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return managedStores.get().stream();
    }
}

class Store {
    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        if (!manager.equals(this.manager)) {
            this.manager.purgeCache();
            this.manager = manager;
            this.manager.purgeCache();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, if you really really want to maintain references in both directions then you will need each update to automatically change the reference in the other direction. This is a notoriously error prone approach. Once your model gets complex it's easy to have hard-to-detect reference corruption creep in (e.g. via a subclass that overrides the setter without calling the superclass's setter). Avoid this if you can.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, we'll assume the managers table has `ID` primary key, and stores table has `manager` field that references the managers `ID`.

So `SELECT` your `managers` data from the DB, loop through the records and build your `managers` objects array.

Next `SELECT` from your `stores` table, loop through those records are start building your `stores` objects array, and in this loop you can have a nested loop to go through your managers array and find the manager the store object/record has referenced, then set that manager for the store, and add the store to the manager's list of stores.

```
//  Assume db_mgrs and db_stores are result sets return from database.
Object[][] db_mgrs = new Object[][]{{0, "Steve"}, {1, "Bob"}, {2, "Nick"}, {3, "Sam"}};
Object[][] db_stores = new Object[][]{{1, "First Store", 0}, {2, "Second Store", 0}, {3, "Third Store", 2}};

ArrayList<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Store> stores = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < db_mgrs.length; i++) {
    managers.add(new Manager((int)db_mgrs[i][0], (String)db_mgrs[i][1]));
}

for(int i = 0; i < db_stores.length; i++) {
    stores.add(new Store((int)db_stores[i][0], (String)db_stores[i][1]));
    for(int j = 0; j < managers.size(); j++) {
        if(db_stores[i][2].equals(managers.get(j).getId())) {
            stores.get(i).setMgr(managers.get(j));
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < stores.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(stores.get(i).getMgrName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use this design (or a variation of it as per your schema) to build the two way mapping:

**Store.class**

```
public class Store {

    private Manager manager;
    private final String storeName;

    public Store(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public String getStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }
}
```

**Manager.class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Manager {

    private List<Store> stores;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public Manager(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public List<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void assignStore(Store store) {
        if (stores == null) {
            stores = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        stores.add(store);
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

**RetailCorp.class (build the mapping):**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RetailCorp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //This is simulating list of managers from a data store
        List<Manager> managerList = getManagerData();

        //This is simulating list of stores from a data store. Each store has a manager assigned to it.
        List<Store> storeList = getStoreData(managerList);

        System.out.println("=== Now, look through each store and assign managers their list of stores");
        for (int i = 0; i < storeList.size(); i++) {
            Store currentStore = storeList.get(i);
            currentStore.getManager().assignStore(currentStore);
        }

        //Output stores and their managers
        showStoresAndTheirManagers(storeList);

        //Output managers and their stores
        showManagersAndTheirStores(managerList);
    }

    private static List<Manager> getManagerData() {
        System.out.println("=== Building manager data");
        List<Manager> managerList = new ArrayList<>();
        int totalManagers = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalManagers; i++) {
            managerList.add(new Manager("FN-" + i, "LN-" + i));
        }
        return managerList;
    }

    private static List<Store> getStoreData(List<Manager> managerList) {
        System.out.println("=== Building stores data");
        List<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<>();
        int totalStores = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStores; i++) {
            storeList.add(new Store("Store " + i));
        }
        storeList.get(0).setManager(managerList.get(0));    //store 0 -> manager 0
        storeList.get(1).setManager(managerList.get(1));    //store 1 -> manager 1
        storeList.get(2).setManager(managerList.get(0));    //store 2 -> manager 0
        return storeList;
    }

    private static void showStoresAndTheirManagers(List<Store> storeList) {
        System.out.println("=== Print stores and their manager");
        for (int i = 0; i < storeList.size(); i++) {
            Store currentStore = storeList.get(i);
            System.out.println(currentStore.getStoreName() + " has Manager: " + currentStore.getManager().getFullName());
        }
    }

    private static void showManagersAndTheirStores(List<Manager> managerList) {
        System.out.println("=== Print managers and their stores");
        for (int i = 0; i < managerList.size(); i++) {
            Manager currentManager = managerList.get(i);
            System.out.println("Manager: " + currentManager.getFullName() + " has total " + currentManager.getStores().size() + " stores");
            currentManager.getStores().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getStoreName()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Run output**

```
=== Building manager data
=== Building stores data
=== Now, look through each store and assign managers their list of stores
=== Print stores and their manager
Store 0 has Manager: FN-0 LN-0
Store 1 has Manager: FN-1 LN-1
Store 2 has Manager: FN-0 LN-0
=== Print managers and their stores
Manager: FN-0 LN-0 has total 2 stores
Store 0
Store 2
Manager: FN-1 LN-1 has total 1 stores
Store 1
```